# Postman post image data to strapi

Tags: postman, strapi

I'm able to post data "title" and "sequence" using POST in postman.

However, how should I post the image? What about multiple images as well?

I've tried using

1)Body with form-data, img as key and place a file in it, however the img is still null. Response:

```
{
    "title": "test title 2",
    "sequence": 5,
    "_id": "5bd1658f39702a5df8a1e447",
    "createdAt": "2018-10-25T06:41:19.197Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-10-25T06:41:19.358Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "img": null,
    "id": "5bd1658f39702a5df8a1e447"
}
```

2) Convert the image to base 64 string and post it as json:

Request:

```
{
  "title": "test title 3",
  "sequence": 6
  "img": "base64stringxxxxx"
}
```

Response:

```
{
    "message": "An internal server error occurred",
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked what requests browser does when you upload a file manually?
Most likely image should be sent as multipart not in body as base64.

Comment: Thanks klubi, seems like it's really is multipart. I need to call the http://localhost:1337/upload to upload the file, next post the new entry, and update/put the img link